# Did I fry my digital clock when soldering it?

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, electronics

I got a new digital clock for my car (1988 Accord) as the old one was broken. It came without that front cover/bezel/plastic chassis so I intended to swap it into the old bezel/plastic chassis from the broken clock.

Before doing this I was able to plug it in and test it - it worked fine.

So, I simply soldered the wiring from the new clock onto the socket-pins embedded into the old clock's bezel/chassis (the socket is part of the plastic casing).

And it no longer works. I tested power to the circuit board and that's all good, but the clock its self is just not working.

Could it be possible that when soldering on the wires to the socket-pins I some how heated up the circuit board? I'm puzzled as to how this could've happened.
[image: Old, Broken clock]

[image: New, Working clock]

Comment: Can you add some photos?

Comment: Did you connect the wires with the correct polarity?

Comment: @HandyHowie I believe I did (I took photos). The only difference was a one of the four wires was a different colour (green VS yellow). Will upload photos I have shortly.

Comment: Tried to upload photos but it seems Imgur is down?

Comment: The black wire is in the same place on both photos, but the coloured wires are in totally different places.  Is that correct?  How did you know where to connect the different coloured wires?